# Lightbox effect for JWPlayer

Tags: lightbox, jwplayer

Can anyone tell how to set up a lightbox-style effect for JWPlayer?  For example, click any of the thumbnails on the VideoHive home page:  http://videohive.net/.  Then click video preview and the JWPlayer opens like a lightbox image.  In some cases the player will be resized as well, but not full-screen.  How is all of that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working using the inline lightbox settings feature of the Lightbox Plus plugin, as described here:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/27431/running-jw-player-in-a-lightbox